# Trace a binary stream from a device file

Tags: pipe, tail, binary

I'm debugging a binary stream that is coming from a device file. 
I would like to have the output printed out in real time as hex values.

So far I've used `tail -f /dev/ttyAPP2 | hexdump -C` but after I started missing some bytes in the output I understood that this could be a bad choice because it doesn't flush the data until a newline character is found.

There is an unofficial [binary tail](http://kk5jy.net/bintail/) but I currently can't use that approach and am looking for a suggestion how to achieve this with other means?

## Example

First the tty is set to raw mode.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAPP2 raw
```

Here is what I get when listening to the device (this is real output)

```
root@Vdevice:/dev# hexdump -C < /dev/ttyAPP2
00000000  55 00 21 00 02 26 00 02  0b 00 09 02 06 01 00 01  
00000010  99 0c ec 45 4f 01 03 47  41 54 45 57 41 59 43 54
```

However, the expected package should be (this isn't a real output):

```
root@Vdevice:/dev# hexdump -C < /dev/ttyAPP2
00000000  55 00 21 00 02 26 00 02  0b 00 09 02 06 01 00 01  
00000010  99 0c ec 45 4f 01 03 47  41 54 45 57 41 59 43 54  
00000020  52 4c 00 00 00 00 00 8b
```

The other part of the package gets printed out on arrival of the second package (this is real output)

```
root@Vdevice:/dev# hexdump -C < /dev/ttyAPP2
00000000  55 00 21 00 02 26 00 02  0b 00 09 02 06 01 00 01  
00000010  99 0c ec 45 4f 01 03 47  41 54 45 57 41 59 43 54
00000020  52 4c 00 00 00 00 00 8b  55 00 21 00 02 26 00 02
00000030  0b 00 09 02 06 01 00 01  99 0c ec 45 4f 01 03 47
00000040  41 54 45 57 41 59 43 54  52 4c 00 00 00 00 00 8b
```

Comment: does `od -x < /dev/ttyAPP2` have the right format?

Comment: sounds like `xxd /dev/ttyAPP2 ` might be what you're looking for

Comment: Interacting directly with the device like this can create unintentional blocking on the original stream, which probably isn't desirable as this will interfere with the data flow you're trying to observe. It may be better to trace the process already reading the device file and capture the data as its read by that process. What is doing the reading of that binary stream?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I need to continuously monitor the device file for new data.

Comment: @SteveBonds No other application is communicating with the file.

Comment: `tail -f` is rarely useful for files other than regular files. Why aren't you using `</dev/ttyAPP2 hexdump -C` ?

Comment: @Gilles The example you gave doesn't continuously track the file. It ends and returns to the shell.

Comment: @Alan It only stops if it reaches the end of file. That doesn't usually happen with devices. Can't you configure your device not to send EOF, as explained in mikeserv's answer?

Comment: @Gilles Updated the question based on your suggestion. `<` redirects as soon as there is something readable? I'm starting to doubt it could be some internal buffer of `/dev/ttyAPP2` preventing real time printing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to `tail -f` a tty. If it's sending you EOF, or, if it is line-buffering, then you need to configure it.

```
stty -F/dev/ttyAPP2 raw
```

Now you can...

```
cat /dev/ttyAPP2
```

...as needed...

You might try...

```
</dev/ttyAPP2 \
dd bs=16 conv=sync | od -vtx1
```

...which will sync out every successful `read()` from your device into 16-byte, null-padded blocks, and so will write line-buffered output *(such as to your terminal)* in real-time regardless of throughput, though any trailing nulls might distort your stream.

With GNU `stdbuf` and a dynamically linked `od`:

```
stdbuf -o0 od -vtx1 </dev/ttyAPP2
```

...would write output in real-time regardless.

You might also buffer to a temp file like...

```sh
f=$(mktemp)
exec 3<>"$f"; rm -- "$f"
while   dd >&3 of=/dev/fd/1 bs=4k count=1
        [ -s /dev/fd/3 ]
do      od -An -vtx1 /dev/fd/3
        echo
done    </dev/ttyAPP2 2>/dev/null
```

...which, though likely not nearly as efficient as the other recommendations, might be worth considering if you wanted to delimit reads from your device by EOF. I find the technique useful sometimes when working with ttys, anyway.

It is also possible to force `hexdump` to print out less bytes by using the custom print format. The example below will print every time there are 4 bytes available:

`hexdump -e '4/1 "%02x " "\n"'  < /dev/ttyAPP2`

Comment: I've updated the question. `...which will sync out every successful read() from your device` seems like it could be an issue with the tty buffer size

Comment: @Alan.... no. Its to do with `od`'s output buffer, actually. See how there are 16 bytes per line there? `hexdump` *(though you'd do better w/ `od`)* will do 16 bytes per line and it will write output to a terminal one line at a time. `dd` doesn't have that problem, and it writes output as soon as it arrives. But in order to flush `od`'s output in the same way, you've got to block out at 16 bytes per `dd` write - which is what `dd` is used for there. Any input shy of 16 bytes will get null-padding to equal 16, and so `od` will always write a line of output as soon as any input is available.

Comment: @Alan - or you could use one of the other two options as well. `stdbuf` is a likely candidate. GNU `od` also has the `-w`idth setting - you could do `-w1`, for example, and write a line per byte.

Comment: Great reasoning, thank you :)
I will do some research on it and once I get the proof of concept running will accept the answer. I'm in bad luck to be running busybox versions of `dd` and `od` on the platform :p

Comment: @Alan - yeah, you are. you should fix that. `busybox` has *horrible* versions of those utilities. get [`toybox`](http://www.landley.net/toybox/).

Answer (score 2):

if multiline (9 lines) solution is ok, check below `hextail.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#par1==buffsize, par2=xxd-columns-width, par3=sleepVal;    defaults: 256 16 0
size=${1:-256}; cols=${2:-16}; cnt=0; hbuff=$(eval printf '00%.0s' {1..$size})
while true; do
   hbuff=${hbuff:2}$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null | xxd -p) #shiftLeft, add 1b
   printf '\033[;H'; xxd -r -p <<<$hbuff | xxd -g1 -c$cols #cursor gotoxy 1,1
   echo total bytes: $((++cnt)) ;   [ -z $3 ] || sleep $3  #...and buff show.
done
```

it implements binary tail by storing its hex representation in bash string variable. First byte in buff deleted on appending new byte at the end.

example test commands:

```
1) cat /dev/urandom | ./hextail.sh 1024 32 0.2      ...with 200ms sleep
2) ./hextail.sh < /dev/ttyAPP2
```